# Grab YouTube Thumbnail AFTER Post?

Tags: rss, post-thumbnails, youtube

I'm using a feed to receive special YouTube feeds organized via playlists. Unfortunately, the URL is not included in the description field, but I can get the videos to display by including the source URL on post.

This works fine except since the URL is not in the post area in the editor, the YouTube thumbnail grabbers I have tried don't retrieve these thumbnails.

Does anyone know a way I can fetch the featured image through the published version of the post? It needs to be automated because I have way to many post items to adjust them manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each YouTube video has 4 generated images. They are predictably formatted as follows

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

The first one in the list is a full size image and others are thumbnail images.

so if you have the video url the you can extract the video id from it call your image, and to do that on posts that are already posted you can use `the_content` filter hook.

Comment: Are you suggesting to add this to the loop? I understand the concept, but not how you're insinuated I implement it.

Comment: no, not the loop, using `add_filter('the_content',you_function');` and in your_function you do what you want so you dont have to change your theme or posts/pages

Comment: can I use this method to inject a "featured" image rather than just calling an image? Youtube videos aren't the only thing that gets posted on the site.

Comment: Yes, Lookup wordpres image sideload or post a new question.

Comment: Glad i could help